# which disk in HDD/SSD caddy?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I want to use an SSD caddy in order to install an SSD disc in my laptop. The main OS of the laptop is Linux, and additionally I want to work with Windows via the SSD.

Yet, it is often recommended to use the in-build disk as main and the second disc *(in caddy)* as storage, thus install the SSD on the board and the HHD in the caddy.

I wander if installing a disc for OS purposes *(Windows)* in caddy, would cause and problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is often recommended to use the in-build disk as main and the second 
>   disc (in caddy) as storage

There are only two reason I can think off why you would always want to do this:

1. Less work. If the HDD is already in its normal place, there is no need to move it.
2. The internal disk might be on a different controller, possibly needing a reinstallation of windows if you move it. (though probably not needing that if you run BSD or Linux).

IN modern laptops you often have enough SATA ports on a ICHx or more modern that point #2 no longer applies. And personally I run my old disk in the DVD->HDD caddy and a SSD in the internal bay of my E6500.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. Running a secondary OS from caddy should affect reliability or performance?

Comment: No, secondary (or primary ot tertiarry or ...) OS should run just fine. No reason to put the SSD in the caddy or not to place it there. Both internal and caddy should work equally fine.